# SQL, varchar field with decimals entries = ORDER BY not sorting proprely

Tags: php, mysql, sql, math, numbers

So i have a table with a VARCHAR field. It is used to sort a lot of decimals value:

Let's say i have the following entries in my VARCHAR field:

- 9.99
- 263.28
- 9.98

Let's say I want to display all entries using ORDER BY varchar DESC. The result would be:

- 9.99
- 9.98
- 263.28

When obviously `263.28` should be the first one. What's wrong ?

Comment: `DESC` is descending order. If you want it from low to high then replace `DESC` with `ASC` or remove the `DESC`.

Comment: No i want it DESC but the biggest number isn't showing first.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing numbers in a varchar column in the first place. If you were using a proper numeric type, the ordering would be just fine.

Answer (score 6):

If you have all decimal values in varchar field then just convert it to decimal and then apply order by clause. I have not much idea about mysql data type and convert function, but in MS SQL you can convert it to decimal like

```
ORDER BY CAST(field AS DECIMAL(18,2)) DESC
```

**UPDATE :**

Yes, in MySQL also there is cast function :  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: I'm with mysql. What does the 18,2 stands for ?

Comment: 18 is length of decimal with 2 precision

Comment: But what if my decimals have different lenght in the database ?

Comment: What is mean by different length ? In MySQL also there is CAST function. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: Life saver answer

Answer (score 1):

If you order by a varchar column, mysql will sort alphabetically. The first character "2" comes before "9". That's why you get the order you see. Cast the varchar column to decimal in the order by clause and it should work as you expect.

Alternatively, you could update "9.99" to "009.99" and so on so that all the rows have the same number of characters. Then the alphabetical sort will match the numerical sort. I'm not suggesting you actually use that as a solution - it just shows you how things work in the database.

Comment: How do i cast the decimal thing with mysql ? Never done that before. The decimal data in my database is coming from a custom php script, so i could probably edit the script to use decimals with the same number of characters. Is there a php function to do that automatically ?

Comment: The code in the other answer should work fine. The link from Upendra Chaudhari explains more about the cast function.