# how do you order numbers such as 1.01,1.01.2 in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a column that a user can enter numbers like 1.01. so my table in sql ends up looking like

```
Id
1.01
1.03.04
2.1
1.01.01
1.
2.
1.02
```

how can i order this column so that it looks like

```
1.
1.01
1.01.01
1.02
1.03.04
2.
2.1
```

If it was 2 decimal places i would have cast it as a decimal, but this doesnt work for this instance since i have numbers like 1.01.01

found reference [SQL, varchar field with decimals entries = ORDER BY not sorting proprely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874402/sql-varchar-field-with-decimals-entries-order-by-not-sorting-proprely)

Comment: Look into using something like a `hierarchyid` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larnu suggested, hierarchyid ... but this took a little cleanup like leading zeros and the double/trailing //

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Id] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1.01')
,('1.03.04')
,('2.1')
,('1.01.01')
,('1.')
,('2.')
,('1.02')
 
Select * 
 from  @YourTable
 Order by try_convert(hierarchyid,replace('/'+replace(replace(ID,'.0','.'),'.','/')+'/','//','/'))
```

**Results**

```
Id
1.
1.01
1.01.01
1.02
1.03.04
2.
2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2016+

Split string by "." separator (using JSON to get correct order of values), then pivot split values, then order by pivoted columns:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE ([OriginalInsertedOrderID] INT IDENTITY(1,1), [Value] VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @YourTable([Value]) VALUES 
 ('1.01')
,('1.03.04')
,('2.1')
,('1.01.01')
,('1.')
,('2.')
,('1.02')
,('1.02')
;

SELECT p.Value 
FROM (
    SELECT t.OriginalInsertedOrderID,t.[Value],s.[Value] AS [v],s.[Key]+1 AS [ordinal]
    FROM @YourTable t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(('["'+REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(t.[Value],'json'),'.','","')+'"]'),'$') s
) a
PIVOT(MAX(a.[v]) FOR a.ordinal IN ([1],[2],[3])) p
ORDER BY p.[1],p.[2],p.[3],p.OriginalInsertedOrderID
;
```